# Comment author's username shifts downward (compared to the rest of the line) on narrow screens

Tags: bug, comments, design, localization, stack-exchange-team

On narrow screens (e.g., Android Chrome), the username of a comment author is displayed shifted downward in the [comment section](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12247/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-gpt-%D0%B8-chatgpt-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0#comment52907_12247) (especially for users with the "Staff" and "Mod" labels):

> [image]

Other comments for this user could be found [here](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=activity&sort=comments).

[A comment](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5469/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE#comment20578_5470) from another team staff looks formatted correctly:

> [image]

Comment: I did some testing myself to figure out what causes this to happen... Specifically, it looks like this shifting happens when the width of the comment area is too narrow to properly display the dash (`–`) followed by the username (and any user labels that follow it) on the same line; instead of wrapping onto multiple lines, it looks like the page attempts to keep all of that on the same line – and for whatever reason, it pushes the username down.

Comment: (Also, this isn't limited to those with "Mod" and/or "Staff" badges; at a narrow enough width, this can happen for commenters with long usernames too.)